# The createbundle command requests parameters

Tags: install4j

When I try to create a bundle with everything on default, I get this:

```
C:\Users\tkd6u\AppData\Local\Temp\bundle>\Daten\software\install4j7\bin\createbundle.exe
Usage: createbundle [OPTIONS] [JRE home directory]
Try 'createbundle --help for more information'

C:\Users\tkd6u\AppData\Local\Temp\bundle>
```

It tells me that all parameters are optional, but complains about wrong usage - what am I supposed to do here?
(This is install4j7.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "JRE home directory" parameter is actually not optional, you have to supply the installation directory of a JRE.